# What is the purpose of SwUpdate.activateUpdate() in Angular?

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#forcing-update-activation) provides following example to activate an SW update:

```
constructor(updates: SwUpdate) {
  updates.available.subscribe(event => {
    if (promptUser(event)) {
        updates.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
    }
  });
}
```

From what I observe, the call itself is not sufficient to activate new version, reload is necessary. However `document.location.reload()` is sufficient even without `activateUpdate()` call.

What is the purpose of `activateUpdate()` call? Why call it at all when reload suffice?

Comment: Have you discovered an answer to this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some background on what the Angular ServiceWorker does under the hood:

- There is always one version of the SW, but it can have multiple versions of the app.
- It keeps a mapping of [client IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/id) to app versions, so it knows which version to serve to each client.
- When a new version is found, it downloads it and marks it as the latest version.
- From that point onwards, new clients (e.g. new tabs) will be served that latest version, but existing clients (tabs) will still get their previously assigned version.

This behavior is a little different than how ServiceWorkers usually work. It is designed to allow serving the latest version to new clients, but not break existing ones (by serving them new content that is not designed to work with the older HTML/CSS/JS code they are using already).

---

Now, back to `activeUpdate()`:

This basically tells the SW to assign the latest version to the client. Once the operation completes, new requests from the client will be served with the latest app version. This is not safe, therefore it is recommended to reload the page to ensure that all code comes from the new version.

---

Does simply reloading suffice?

This basically depends on how browsers assign `Client.id` on reloads. If the browser assigns a new ID to the tab on reload, then the SW will serve the latest version anyway, so `swUpdate.activeUpdate()` is not necessary. If, on the other hand, the browser keeps the same client ID, then the SW would serve the old version without `swUpdate.activeUpdate()`.

Currently, Chrome seems to assign a new ID (and therefore `activeUpdate()` is unnecessary before reload). I couldn't find something conclusive in [the SW spec](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker), so I am not sure whether this is per the spec and whether all browsers do the same.
(It is also possible that browsers used to behave differently in the past, making `activeUpdate()` necessary, but the spec/browsers have been updated since, making it redundant if you plan to reload.)

---

So, if you verify that your supported browsers behave as expected in that regard, then you don't need to call `activeUpdate()` before reloading.

Note that the documentation example is just a simplified illustration of the APIs that are available. In a real app, there are several ways to handle the update (depending on the app's requirements).

For example, you could:

1. Activate the update immediatelly (if you are certain that your app can handle that) and not reload.
2. Show a notification that an update is available and let the user click to reload (and thus update).
3. Let the app know that an update is available and have it automatically reload on the next in-app navigation. (This is what we do in https://angular.io/ btw.)

<sub>Again, not all strategies are suitable for all types of apps, so choose the one that works best for you.</sub>

---

***EDIT:***
*BTW, if you have suggestions on how the documentation could be improved, please open an issue (or better yet submit a pull request)!*

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Can you explain how to code that third option of reloading the page on the next in-app navigation?

Comment: Also about the first (update immediately). Does that mean part of the application/modules/services will have the new code, if so which parts? It would seem like a good option to just say: page was opened and an update is ready so since the user just arrived, let's activate the new version (if it is safe code-wise).

Comment: Regarding the first question, the relevant code from angular.io is https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fbf40bf4000944c06458472142ca967ef8d3b1d/aio/src/app/sw-updates/sw-updates.service.ts, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fbf40bf4000944c06458472142ca967ef8d3b1d/aio/src/app/shared/location.service.ts#L39 and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fbf40bf4000944c06458472142ca967ef8d3b1d/aio/src/app/shared/location.service.ts#L49-L53.

Comment: I don't understand the second question :D

Comment: Your first option was "Activate the update immediatelly... if the app can handle". What are the conditions to make sure the app can handle the update without reload? My guess would be: some modules were already loaded so old code, but other modules will be loaded with new code. If that's the case I guess it's pretty hard to make sure the app can handle it without reloading...

Comment: Yes, exactly. This strategy is not suitable for most apps. But if, for example, you are certain your app will not load any more code without a reload (i.e. there are no lazy-loaded modules, etc.) you might be fine.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the ideas @gkalpak

Comment: Thanks @gkalpak for this wonderful answer. Learnt a lot and many questions has been answered as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the github code, what I understand is, an `activateUpdate()` will do a postMessage() to the service worker thread to let it know about the new data and status and once the promise has been resolved(service worker thread knows about it), then reload the page.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.11/packages/service-worker/src/update.ts#L57-L64

```
activateUpdate(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.sw.isEnabled) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(ERR_SW_NOT_SUPPORTED));
    }
    const statusNonce = this.sw.generateNonce();
    return this.sw.postMessageWithStatus('ACTIVATE_UPDATE', {statusNonce}, statusNonce);
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/service-worker/src/low_level.ts#LC105

```
postMessageWithStatus(type: string, payload: Object, nonce: number): Promise<void> {
    const waitForStatus = this.waitForStatus(nonce);
    const postMessage = this.postMessage(type, payload);
    return Promise.all([waitForStatus, postMessage]).then(() => undefined);
}
```

Comment: This still does not explay the why, what is the difference to simply reloading the page?