# Angular PWA, how to prompt a message to users so they can know and reload app after i deploy new code

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have researched and I know many people have asked about this problem but I still can not solve the problem that I am having. So I will make the question again.

I am developing an application use Angular PWA.
I want every time after I deploy, the app will prompt a message and the user clicks on it to reload the app.

Currently, i have used SwUpdate to check available new version but it doesn't prompt message for me (I have changed title in the index.html file and update some code at some other components).

I have create a service called PwaUpdateService, in this service i have defined method checkForUpdates(). After that, i call that method in the AppComponent.

**Here is my code:**

```
import {SwUpdate} from '@angular/service-worker';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {interval} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PwaUpdateService {
  updateSubscription;

  constructor(public updates: SwUpdate) {
  }

  public checkForUpdates(): void {
    this.updateSubscription = this.updates.available.subscribe(event => this.promptUser());

    if (this.updates.isEnabled) {
      // Required to enable updates on Windows and ios.
      this.updates.activateUpdate().then();

      interval(60 * 60 * 1000).subscribe(() => {
        this.updates.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
          // console.log('checking for updates');
        });
      });

    }

    // Important: on Safari (ios) Heroku doesn't auto redirect links to their https which allows the installation of the pwa like usual
    // but it deactivates the swUpdate. So make sure to open your pwa on safari like so: https://example.com then (install/add to home)
  }

  promptUser(): void {
    this.updates.activateUpdate().then(() => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  }
}
```

**In the AppComonent:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private screen: ScreenService,
              private sw: PwaUpdateService) {

    // check the service worker for updates
    this.sw.checkForUpdates();
  }
}
```

That's the code that I followed Angular's tutorial but had no luck.

Thanks for taking the time to look at my questions, hope you can help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You (as a developer) are responsible of showing something to the user, this is not included in the `SwUpdate` service.

Here is an example working with a [`MatSnackBar`](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UpdateService {

  constructor(
    private swUpdate: SwUpdate,
    private snackbar: MatSnackBar,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string,
    appRef: ApplicationRef
  ) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
        const snack = this.snackbar.open('New version available!', 'Refresh');

        snack.onAction().pipe(switchMap(() => this.swUpdate.activateUpdate())).subscribe(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
          snack.dismiss();
        }, 6000);
      });

      // Poll logic after isStable, otherwise isStable never fires
      appRef.isStable.pipe(
        first(stable => stable),
        switchMap(() => interval(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) // Every 6h
      ).subscribe(() => {
        this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Note: forget about the `platformId` if your app doesn't include server-side rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as i see from your code. The app will prompt a message if there is new version available immediately after user reload page (AppComponent trigger UpdateService to check new version). As i know, the browsers always get new release files after user reload page, so why we need to do that?

Ignore the case prompt a message to user.
I want my app will auto reload if there is new version so i have set interval to check every one minutes. checkForUpdate method is called but response is null. And this.updates.available.subscribe doesn't trigger to reload page.

Comment: As you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494181/what-is-the-purpose-of-swupdate-activateupdate-in-angular browsers don't necessarily assign a new ID to the client when reloading the page, `activateUpdate()` makes the behavior consistent between browsers.

Comment: I have added console.log to check current version and available version after i call this.swUpdate.available.subscribe. However, this.swUpdate.available.subscribe wasn't triggered, i don't see that console.log after i reload page (I have updated some things and then deployed the new version). 

So i think that this.swUpdate.available.subscribe doesn't work for me now => the app can't automatically reload.

Comment: Do you see a request like `/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.6439254620524275`? Also do you publish the `ngsw.json` file on your webserver after every build?

Comment: Yes, i see that request and i make sure the ngsw.json was published to webserver. Besides, i have checked in Application tab -> Service Worker and see that it has been installed. However, there is a weird issue, service worker doesn't cache all resources when running app on my desktop, but when running on other desktops then it cache all. Also SwUpdate work on those other desktops but not work on my desktop, i have checked chrome version, doesn't disable cache. So i think the problem is by my desktop. Do you know why happen that weird  issue?

Comment: I actually don't know about this inconsistency between browsers. I suggest you write a new question about it because your initial question was about notifying the users that a new version is available

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @GuerricP Do you know if the update text 'New version available!' can customized / set by the newer version of the Angular app without using an extra API. For example, I want it to give a brief description of the update. I read the doc here https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwUpdate but it doesn't seem to have that function

Comment: @Jun711 it's your responsibility to implement your own code to notify the user. In my example I am using Angular Material's snackbar but it could be anything else.

Comment: @GuerricP My question is not about Angular Material's snackbar. I mean if the text 'New version available!'  can be set by the newer version of the app without an extra REST API.

Comment: OK I got it well no at that point the running code is still the old one so you can't display anything from the new version