# Angular Service Worker flawless and silent upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker, angular-services, angular-service-worker

I am using Angular Service Work API https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro

What I want to achieve to have better experience from the user where in the update of service worker will be a silent upgrade in background without refreshing the page flawlessly. The actual process is right now is by reloading the page. This is poor user experience in real world scenario.

1. Does Angular supports silent upgrade?
2. Is the service worker can be customize to achieve flawless and silent upgrade of the service worker?

I would like to share the current code that I am using to get the latest version of the app which then showing a snackbar that latest version is available and do a refresh.

```
 runNewAppVersionNotifier() {
        const self = this;
        console.log('log notifier 1', self.swUpdate.isEnabled);
        if (self.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
            console.log('log swUpdate 2', self.swUpdate.isEnabled);
            self.swUpdate.available.subscribe((event) => {
                console.log('log notified available', event);
                self.matSnackBar.openFromComponent(JepSnackbarComponent, {
                    duration: 0, data: { text: "New version available. Please reload the page to get the latest update.", withButton: true, customTextButton: "RELOAD", status: "info" }
                }).afterDismissed().subscribe((result: any) => {
                    console.log('log swupdate fire', result);
                    self.swUpdate.activateUpdate().then((value) => {
                        window.location.reload();
                        const hostname = window.location.hostname;
                        let c = new CookieStorage({ domain: hostname === "localhost" ? "localhost" : ".jepto.com", secure: hostname === "localhost" ? false : true, path: "/" });
                        c.clear();
                    });
                    // if (result === true) {

                    // }
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Already fixed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494181/what-is-the-purpose-of-swupdate-activateupdate-in-angular/59175788#59175788