# Angular Service Worker - do hard reload on user navigation via router if update is available

Tags: angular, service-worker, updates, angular-service-worker

We have implemented the angular service worker in our app and are unhappy with having to ask the user to do a hard reload some seconds after the app has loaded.

Our idea was to trigger the hard reload when the user changes the route anyway - to intercept the angular navigation event and convert it to a window.location change. This would sneak in the hard reload without the user having to explicitly confirm.

Has anybody already tried this approach? Are there reference implementations? Are there any obvious problems we are missing?

Comment: Why do you need a hard reload? Angular takes care about updates. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: You are right in the normal case, but according to the documentation here, it does not, when using a service worker (the app can be served from the cache, and updates are lazy-loaded. to switch you need the user triggering a reload) https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#updating-to-the-latest-version

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175788/5790305) it must be possible:

> Let the app know that an update is available and have it automatically reload on the next in-app navigation. (This is what we do in https://angular.io/ btw.)

The process might be as follows:

1. Observe available update

```
    swUpdate.versionUpdates.subscribe(evt => {
      if (evt.type === 'VERSION_READY') {
          console.log('New app version ready for use');
          /** TODO: save state that update is ready */
      }
    });
```

2. On navigation end activate update and reload page

```
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        filter(event => {
           /** TODO: if state says update is ready return true */
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.swUpdate.activateUpdate()),
      )
      .subscribe(() => document.location.reload());
```

In theory, according to the mentioned post, you do not even need to call `activateUpdate()`. Just reload the page.